# Wordpress Multisite and site speed and scaleability

Tags: authentication, globals

We have a multisite wordpress setup like this:
domain.com/nz domain.com/au domain.com/us etc. I would like to know the best approach for the best setup so we can give each country the best site speed and load times and also being able to scale the website. 
If we host in Us then NZ users get a slow loading page. If we host in NZ then Us get a slow loading experience.

Once option is to break the sites out into single Wordpress sites but we will also have a forum which is a global site and an application domain say domain.com/app or app.domain.com which we ideally would like the user to be automatically logged into from their respective country site. The app needs to be global so all users of all sub country sites can interact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) to serve the content to users from the closest server to them.

Comment: We did have a CDN in place but that did not make the biggest difference.

Comment: @user3691715 Well, yeah. Having a server in the same country also does not make a big difference, if you ask me. I wouldn't even do that. Just optimize the sites in other ways. A caching plugin and a good theme is what makes a difference.